# Every time I restart my computer I need to restart Bluetooth service, how can I fix this?

Tags: linux-mint, services, bluetooth

Every time I turn on, restart or wake up my notebook or I have to restart my Bluetooth service in order for me to use it. But once I restart the service everything is fine. How can I delay the start of the Bluetooth service to keep me from having to restart it?

OS/ Linux Mint 11

Comment: I was about to send you to [Linux Mint's bugtracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/) when I found [a bug report there](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/789023) that remarkably sounds like what you describe.  Maybe it's worthwhile for you to jump in there.

Comment: @sr_ your comment sounds like an answer.

Comment: uhm...right... added one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Have a look at this bug report.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/789023) (Maybe you can help them fix it)